# Loading the database for testing with Mocha and Chai

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to run some test implying Moongoose and database calls using Mocha and Chai but the test fails at the database request with no warning at all. I might be making a mistake somewhere.

Here is the test file:

```
'use strict';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbtest', function(err, res) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Error connecting to the database. ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to Database: ' + config.mongoURI[app.settings.env]);
  }
});
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect; // we are using the "expect" style of Chai
var ScoreAction = require('./../../model/GTscoreAction.js');
describe('ScoreAction', function() {
  it('newFriend', function() {
    expect(ScoreAction.addNewFriend(12, 155).toEqual(1));
  });
});
```

And the GTscoreAction.js method:

```
ScoreActionSchema.statics.addNewFriend = function(userID, friendFacebookID) {
  ScoreAction.findOne({
    _user: userID,
    type : 1,
    data: friendFacebookID
  }).exec(function(err, sa) {
    if (sa)
      return 0;
    return 1;      
  });
}
```

This always fails on the "ScoreAction.findOne" with no warning or error.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The `return 1;` actually is not the return value of `addNewFriend()` function. There is a function inside `.exe()`, can you see it? :)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was helpful with the debugging.